# Applying css styles to sendgrid email python django?

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I am learning to use the sendgrid api with django python. For now, I can successfully send emails but  I would like to make the email more appealing and apply some css styles. I looked online for some help but couldn't find any. Can someone please suggest me how i should go about it ?

This is what i tried so far

```
def sendemail(sender,recipient,subject,content,url):
    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey="*****")
    from_email = Email(sender)
    to_email = Email(recipient)
    subject = subject
    content = Content("text", content+url)

    mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
```

Comment: Styling HTML email is very limited. You should only use inline `style="..."` attributes, not `<style>` tags.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

Comment: https://mailchimp.com/help/css-in-html-email/

Comment: https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-css-inlining-in-email